# asp.net MVC3 project Castle Windsor Error : "No Source Found"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

I'm developing an MVC 3 app. I only have 3 things registered at this point, controller factory, log4net facility and an interface that  binds to a generated service implementation.

This is the error I'm getting:

> “No Source Available”
>
> Castle.Windsor.DLL!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(System.Type
>   implType, object[] arguments, System.Type[] signature) Line 198 + 0x10
>   bytes
>
> Locating source for
>   'e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {b0 a6 78 c5 e8 59 ee 2f 72 e3 ed b 54 48 4 39} The file
>   'e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs'
>   does not exist. Looking in script documents for
>   'e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for
>   'e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project. Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'... The debug source files settings for the
>   active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to
>   find the file:
>   e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file
>   'e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs'.

This started happening after I added the registration installer for my service interface which looks like this:

```
public class MyServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
        Component.For<IServiceBinding>().ImplementedBy<RemoteService>());
    }
}
```

I've got the bootstrap method setup in the global.asax as well. As I said castle was working fine until I added this installer, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the installer. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you tried pulling out Log4Net.. turning on Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions and running the app to see if you get any other detail?  Inner Exceptions or what not?  The source thing is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by replacing my Castle assemblies with the latest version. I'm not sure what caused the error, but it's no longer occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like this in your Global.asax as well?

```
    container = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(FromAssembly.Containing<MyServiceInstaller>());

    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    WindsorResolver.Initialize(container);
```

Comment: This is what I've got in the global at this point:container = new WindsorContainer()
                .Install(FromAssembly.This());
            var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

Comment: No. What Windsor assembly is the WindsorResolver class located in? I have Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor referenced at the moment.

Comment: Oh wait.. sorry about that.  That's something we do ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was able to resolve the issue by updating the Castle assemblies. I'm still not sure what caused the error to occur.